# SW_HIDE doesn't hide my second application C++

Tags: c++, winapi, shellexecute

I'm trying to open an `.exe` file with `ShellExecuteA()` and then hide it. I managed to open the file, but `SW_HIDE` doesn't work on it, but when I try to do the same thing with `notepad.exe`, it works.

```
ShellExecuteA(0, "open", "myapp.exe", 0, 0, SW_HIDE);
```

This opens my application, but doesn't hide it.

I tried putting `myapp.exe` in `System32`, same as where `notepad.exe` is located so I don't need to use any path beside the app name and `.exe` extension, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Is this your own app? `WinMain` has a parameter indicating how you should display the window.

Comment: No, it is 3rd party app. It is not console app, it's with GUI. Could you explain a bit more? Is it possible to do it with ShellExecute?

Comment: There are lots of apps that don't support it, given that it snookers the user.  They can't get back to the user-interface to terminate the app and have to resort to Task Manager to kill it.

Comment: That parameter is passed to the launched executable, but there's no obligation or guarantee that the application will use it for the intended purpose.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's not quite correct (see the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow#remarks) section for `ShowWindow`). By default, and application has no choice but to follow the requested `nCmdShow`. Now, obviously, an application could just call `ShowWindow` twice, but then, maybe you should contact the application publisher's support channel to have them play by the rules.

Comment: have you tried waiting until later to send the SW_HIDE?  It might have hidden something like a splash screen.

Comment: Understanding this requires knowledge of the code that is executing. Not only do we not have this code, apparently you don't either. You don't even tell us what this other program is.